# ESRI UK Productivity Suite: Critical Error - Help Resolving

Tags: arcgis-10.0, extensions

I am using the OS Conversion tool under ProductivitySuite v2.1. to convert OS MasterMap gml to a feature class.

Having carefully followed the instructions I am getting the following: Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57 CRITICAL ERROR: Unable to validate OrderNumber

This is the first time I have used the tool and unsure as to How would I resolve this?

Apparently the data has been copied directly from the CD as it was provided by the OS.

Log File below, if it helps:

18/05/2012 09:56:57 Log File created.
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 =================================================
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 OS Data Converter
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 Version: 2.1 Build: 557
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 Start Processing
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57  Profile name: OS MM SWW
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57  Start condition: New
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 =================================================
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 Validation:
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57  - Validating data order number
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 
**Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57 CRITICAL ERROR: Unable to validate OrderNumber**
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57 CRITICAL ERROR DETAILS:
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57   ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.DataConversionException: Unable to validate OrderNumber ---> System.Exception: Unable to validate order number
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Profile.OrderNumber.Validate(List`1 sourceItems)
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Profile.OrderNumber..ctor(List`1 sourceItems)
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Profile.DataConverterSourceList.ValidateOrderNumber()
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.DC.DataConverterProcess.ValidateOrderNumber()
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.DC.DataConverterProcess.ValidateOrderNumber()
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.DC.DataConverterProcess.DoValidate(String paramName)
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.DataConverterEngine.ValidateProfile()
Error 18/05/2012 09:56:57      at ESRIUK.Products.UKPS.DC.Core.BaseEngine`3.ProcessProfile(T_Profile profile)
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 
Info 18/05/2012 09:56:57 OS Data Converter

many thanks....

Comment: Speak to ESRI - they are usually very responsive.  I can't help with this specific problem as I gave up on Productivity Suite very quickly.  I was using it a couple of years ago and found it to be buggy and limited to importing to MDBs.  I gave up and wrote my own importer based on FME workbench.  Maybe it's better now... but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: This is specific to ESRI (UK) there response will be much slower than ESRI (US) you need your customer number and OS and version of ArcGIS and Productivity Suite (yes there are issues with it) For years they didn't support file geodatabase! for an ESRI products - We had lots of issues converting ITN.

Comment: Service Pack 7 for ArcGIS 10 is here http://www.esriuk.com/software/arcgis/productivitysuite/download

Comment: I gave up and spoke to ESRIUK, it turned out that you can only load files with the same prefix/name - this is the order number. Now I can get the process to run, but my feature classes are empty...another support call...sigh...